# Defining path to run for linux as well as windows

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have c program where i have to save a file in ubuntu. The program runs fine on my local pc but i want to use a single exe for other pcs whether they run linux or windows. So, how should i give path to store file that it works everywhere?

Comment: You cannot do that without runnning emulators or virtual machines.

Comment: @noobkid Use environment variables, but how you go about defining those for each OS will be different. Then in your code you can write the file to `$(MY_EXE_DIR)/file/goes/here`. On Windows `$(MY_EXE_DIR)` could be `C:\Users\MyExe`, in linux it might be `/home/me/MyExe/`. Might be useful to distribute a script/batch file along with your executable to create the variables.

Comment: Oh yeah you will certainly need to compile your source for different targets. If you mean executing the exact same binary on both windows and linux then I'm in agreement with everyone else.

Comment: I want to just deploy the exe. Nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't do what you want.

When an Operating System runs a program, it looks in the file to find things that it needs to know. Windows and Linux store this information in incompatible ways, so you won't be able to create a file that will run under both Windows and Linux.

Comment: But what if there is some way to detect on which os the code is running and use the path accordingly...only windows has a different path style..considering my hypothesis is true then how can one detect the os on which the exe is going to run...at runtime?

Comment: Imagine that you're given a book to read. You're told the book contains instructions to follow, but unfortunately the book has been printed in a language that you don't understand. This is what Windows feels like when it sees a Linux program (or vice-versa).

Comment: Alright. So I'll have to write separate code for linux and windows. :s

Comment: Strictly, you can probably use roughly the same code, but you can't use the same compiled binary. You'll probably need to look into Makefiles (or whatever equivalent your IDE is using)